# Conceptual q about custom UIKit objects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit

Simple question: what is the standard method of creating a customized version of say a UILabel, UIButton, etc. such that I can easily use it in multiple places?  Is it simply to extend the appropriate class:

```
import UIKit

class FormField: UITextField {

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

      //  borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None

    }
}
```

Basically just want to get some default values set for some UI objects so I can easily drop them into the interface when necessary. Not really sure how to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very rare to subclass something like `UILabel`.

The most common approach is a HAS-A pattern, where you let a controller (often a `UIViewController`) manage the view for you and you reuse that. Alternately, you may make a `UIView` that contains the view you want to customize, and customizes it for you (passing along things that need to be passed along).

You can also have a "configure my view this way" function that you can call on an existing standard view. I haven't seen this very often in reusable code. My experience is that these kind of configuration functions turn out to be very app specific, but they're reasonable common.

Things like `UITextField` have delegate methods already, and a common way to customize them is to create a reusable delegate that applies certain behaviors.

It depends of course on what you're trying to achieve, but subclassing is pretty far down on the list of patterns, unless it's a class explicitly designed and documented to be subclassed (like `UIView` or `UIViewController`).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "creating a resuable delegate"? I thought delegates were just protocols, which don't actually appy any behaviors.  I'm a noob when it comes to delegation, but I've been watching tutorials on it and I sort of get it but I don't necessarily see how to apply that to reusing a UITextField.

Comment: The delegate is the object that implements the delegate protocol. If you wanted to reuse the delegate code required to rejects spaces in a text field, you could create a `TextFieldNoSpacesDelegate` object that implements that. Then your `UIViewController` would create one of those, and set it as the delegate for the desired text field.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` and its subclasses have two designated initializers, `-initWithFrame:` and `-initWithCoder:`. The first is for programmatic instantiation while the latter is for views being unpacked from a Storyboard or NIB. Because of this, the common pattern for subclassing `UIView` subclasses is the following (I'm using ObjC but the Swift code should be easy to figure out):

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    // Do your special setup here!
}
```

Then, if you're using the views in Interface Builder, go to the Identity tab on the right-assistant-editor-sidebar, and in the top box where it says `UILabel` or `UIButton`, put in your custom button class name.

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.